# Printf writing extra character on occasion

Tags: c, printf

this is the code, it is supposed to invert a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void StrRev(char str[]) {
    int len=strlen(str);
    char out[len];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        out[i]=str[len-i-1];
    }
    printf("%s",out);
}
int main(void) {
    StrRev("TestString");
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:

```
gnirtStseT
```

actual output:

```
gnirtStseT@
```

the same thing happens with other inputs, while not on some others.

compiled with MingW on Code::Blocks

Comment: missing null terminator.................

Comment: Spaces are not just decoration. Correctly used, they also greatly enhance readability.

Comment: @Sourav sorry, but how do i add that? i'm new to coding.

Comment: The last character in your array needs to be set to `'\0'`, or alternatively, just `0`.

Comment: `char out[len+1];`

Comment: So after your for loop, set out[len]=0.

Comment: Missing null string terminator. Just before you print the string add out[i] = '\0'; That would suffice. and declare out to be out[len+1]

Comment: What WeatherVane said too, or you'll have a buffer overflow.

Comment: just tested that, didn't work

Comment: `#include <string.h>` compilation warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues:

You fail to `#include <string.h>`, so there's no declaration for `strlen`.  So the function is implicitly declared as `int strlen()`.  So add that to the top of the file.

You also aren't adding the null terminating character to your reversed string.

After the `for` loop, set one additional character in the array to 0.  Also, you'll need to make the array one larger to fit it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// import declaration of strlen
#include <string.h>

void StrRev(char str[]) {
    int len=strlen(str);
    char out[len+1];    // increase length to make room for null terminator
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
        out[i]=str[len-i-1];
    }
    out[i]=0;     // add null terminator
    printf("%s",out);
}
int main(void) {
    StrRev("TestString");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it worked. though the #include <string.h> wasn't needed

Comment: @RicardoSilva why then do think the compiler issued a warning about the missing header?

Comment: @Weather your compiler might have given you a warning, but mine didn't, so for me it was not needed.

Comment: Then you don't have the warning level set high enough.

Comment: @RicardoSilva so what do you think is the point of *any* `#include <xxxxx.h>` statement?

Comment: @RicardoSilva Without the `#include` giving you the proper function prototype, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  That means anything can happen, including your program crashing, getting unpredictable results, or appearing to work properly.  In the latter case, you could make some unrelated change and suddenly your program starts crashing.  UB also means you could get different behavior if you run the same program on a different machine or compile it with a different compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` returns the length of the string without the null terminator at the end. So when you're copying over the characters, you're skipping the NULL at the end. If you simply use

```
int len=strlen(str) + 1;
```

instead of

```
int len=strlen(str);
```

Then everything should work.